# Trouble with Full Text Search query

Tags: sql, join, full-text-search

I'm having trouble with this full text search query I'm trying to run.  I need to do a full text search on two tables.  If any of the terms are in either table I need to return the records from the first table.

```
select R.* from Request R 
    inner join Patients P on R.PatientID = P.PatientID
    inner join containstable(Request,(*),@keywords)AS KEY_TBL 
    ON R.RequestID = KEY_TBL.[Key] 
    full outer join 
    (select R.* from Request R 
    inner join Patients P on R.PatientID = P.PatientID
    inner join containstable(Patients,(*),@keywords) AS KEY_TBL2 
    ON P.PatientID = KEY_TBL2.[Key]) as b on R.RequestID = b.RequestID
```

Answer (score 1):

All I needed was a Union instead of a full outer join.

```
select R.* from Request R 
    inner join Patients P on R.PatientID = P.PatientID
    inner join containstable(Request,(*),@keywords)AS KEY_TBL 
    ON R.RequestID = KEY_TBL.[Key] 
    UNION
    select R.* from Request R 
    inner join Patients P on R.PatientID = P.PatientID
    inner join containstable(Patients,(*),@keywords) AS KEY_TBL2 
    ON P.PatientID = KEY_TBL2.[Key]
```